# SSAS - AVG Calculation but when used parent/child dimension use SUM

Tags: performance, ssas, mdx

I have this structure of DWH

**DimRegion**

```
ID  IDParent Level Region       
1 |  NULL    |  0   | World             
2 |   1      |  1   |America
3 |   1      |  1   |Europe
4 |   2      |  2   |USA
5 |   2      |  2   |Canada
6 |   2      |  2   |Mexico
7 |   3      |  2   |Italy
8 |   3      |  2   |France
```

**FactSales**

```
ID  IDDimRegion IDDimDate  Sales 
1 | 7          | 20150101        | 20
2 | 7          | 20150201        | 30
3 | 7          | 20150301        | 40
4 | 4          | 20150101        | 50
5 | 4          | 20150201        | 30
6 | 4          | 20150301        | 40
7 | 5          | 20150101        | 60
8 | 5          | 20150201        | 30
9 | 5          | 20150301        | 60
10| 8          | 20150101        | 10
11| 8          | 20150201        | 10
12  8          | 20150301        | 10
```

etc....

All values from Fact table are connected only to values on level 2 in DimRegion table.

I created cube **[Sales Cube]** in SSAS with:

- parent/child dimension **DimRegion**
- dimension **DimDate**
- Measures with SUM aggregation **[Sales SUM]**

I made calculation **[Measures].[AVG Into higher regions]** which wrap the measure **[Sales SUM]** and do aggregation **AVG** into higher level of regions.

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[AVG Into higher regions] AS 
    CoalesceEmpty
    (
      Avg
      (
        Descendants
        (
          [DimRegion].[IDParent].Children,
         ,LEAVES
        )
       ,[Measures].[Sales SUM]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Sales SUM]
    ) 
   ,VISIBLE = 1 ;
```

but it is very slow when i use this calculation with dimension date and IDDimDate member in MDX query, so i don't know if there is something incorrect in calculation or in this MDX query because it is so slow.

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[AVG Into higher regions] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{ (
DESCENDANTS([DimRegion].[IDParent].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS) * 
[DimDate].[IDDimDate].[IDDimDate].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [Sales Cube]
```

In my tes Data Warehouse i have about 200 rows in fact table and pre-generated 20 years in Date dimension it's 7300 rows so probably it can be caused somehow by Date dimension. But the final fact table will have about 1 million rows so it is bad that on so less rows it is so slow.

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is the point of `CoalesceEmpty` ? if you leave that out of the measure does the measure still work?

Comment: I have the CoalesceEmpty there because the lowest value in parent/child hierarchy has (null) without that so this make that the (null) value is replaced with value from Sales SUM measure

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is the friend of `olap` calculations, in terms of creating sparse calculations that then function in block mode - rather than cell-by-cell calculations.

You inclusion of `CoalesceEmpty` looks to me like NULL will never be encountered - so this will be slow.

Without that function do you get the wrong answer?

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[AVG Into higher regions] AS 
      Avg
      (
        Descendants
        (
          [DimRegion].[IDParent].Children,
         ,LEAVES
        )
       ,[Measures].[Sales SUM]
      )
   ,VISIBLE = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post but it didn't help in performance of that query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-engineer your case to use advantage of OLAP and cubes.

1. Why do you need **Parent-Child** dimension if your data is always at 2nd level and structure is fixed. Change it to regular dimension with Country and Region hierarchies, create flexible relationship `Region -> Country` and custom hierarchy `Country - Region` (see AdventureWorks Customer Dim as an example).
2. Using **SCOPE** - redefine **[Measures].[Sales SUM]** at Country-Region hierarchy and Country level to be calculated as Avg over children.

Comment: My example isn't written so correctly, in reality the value is references to the lowest member of parent/child hierarchy and it can have more than 2 levels